# Triggering a Macro in a different file with a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA code that will trigger another macro in a different file upon opening that file.

I've written the below code but not sure how to progress after opening the file. (the macro i'm trying to trigger in xWB is called "Sub Button_Click()")
This Macro is currently assigned to a button - hence why i'm struggling.

```
Sub Openworkbook_click()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim MainBook As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("C:link to other file")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Err.Number <> 0 Or xWb Is Nothing Then
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox "The filepath for the borkbook to run the Macro is wrong - please 
update", vbCritical, "Wrong path"
GoTo Finish 'Skips down to close
Else
On Error GoTo 0 'Re-enables errors
End If

Application.Run "'" & xWb.Name & "'!Sub Button_Click()"

'Close workfie
xWb.Close False 'Closes the workbook with the macro, doesn't save

Finish:
Set xWb = Nothing
    'Finish on NXD Tab
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NXD Report").Activate
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me trigger the macro?

Answer (score 1):

You can not trigger the Macro if it is tied to the `_click` action.

You can create a sub that is called by the `_click` action and which can also be called from code by VBA.

You would call it using VBA by using something like:

```
str = xWb.Name & "!" & "Macro_For_NXD" 'Create string with file name and add the name of macro
Application.Run str
```

Note: "Macro_For_NXD" is the name of the macro in the workbook being called

Comment: ah ok, hence why its not working! so i've updated my code to include that line after my code however the Str function is getting an error message "argument not optional" 
the macro is now called Macro_For_NXD (and isn't tied to anything)

Comment: I just adjusted my answer to include your macro name and your xWb object name (previously i had mine in there)

Comment: yeah that's what i was using, i get "compile error" and "argument not optional" when i add that line in (i've updated the question to reflect what i've done)

Answer (score 1):

You either click, as mentioned above, or you can do the following:

```
Sub Openworkbook_click()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim MainBook As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("C:my file link")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Err.Number <> 0 Or xWb Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "The filepath for the borkbook to run the Macro is wrong - please update", vbCritical, "Wrong path"
    GoTo Finish 'Skips down to close
Else
    On Error GoTo 0 'Re-enables errors
End If

Set MainBook = Workbooks.Open("C:my current file") 'Not sure what this is for but you may have a use for it.

Application.Run "'" & xWb.Name & "'!Sub Button_Click()"

xWb.Close False 'Closes the workbook with the macro, doesn't save
Finish:
Set xWb = Nothing
Set MainBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I get run time error 1004: says macro may not be available or maybe disabled :/ i've mirrored the same settings the macro i've tried macro with click name and without :/

Comment: wish i had a clue what i was doing! haha

Comment: @PGD15 what line is it crashing for you?

Comment: Application.Run "'" & xWb.Name & "'!Sub Macro_For_NXD()"

Comment: You're using a defined term that rohrl77 gave you below but that's a different approach - just the code I've provided.

Comment: i tried it exactly with what you gave me first, still same issue same line.

Comment: i've update the code in question to what i've been using which gives me the error - obviously i've updated the file link too!

Comment: Can you double-check that the macro name is correct? If the workbook wasn't found the code I've given would basically have told you so it can't be that (`xWb` has been assigned)..

Comment: I have two macro names:
button click() - assigned to a button and 
Macro_For_NXD() - not assigned to button 
both macros are the same and i've tried them both...

Comment: `button click` isn't a valid macro name because there can't be any spaces.. Where is the macro? is it in a worksheet or module?

Comment: modules and i meant Button_click()

Comment: What's the module name? I'll try to fully qualify the code

Comment: "Module3" very creative i know! Or "Module1" both have same code. (Module1 is assigned to a button though)

Comment: Try replacing `Application.Run "'" & xWb.Name & "'!Sub Button_Click()"` with `Application.Run "'" & xWb.Name & "'!Module3.Sub Button_Click()"`.. to be honest, this shouldnt be what's causing you problems but I'm running out of alternatives!

Comment: ugh still the same issue. just will not work cannot see the macro at all... Do i need to add any of the references in to get this to work?

Comment: No.. I don't know what the problem is, sorry

Comment: ah not to worry, was just trying to save myself a couple of mins a day! Many thanks for all the help though!